# Most efficient way to make a buffer list thing?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I'm looking for a point in the right direction.

I'm in need of a List/Array/?? of a fixed size that I can add to the front, move all elements by one index and push the last element out.

Is it best to just code this behavior and if so are there any best practices to follow? or is there a something that can do this in .net core already?

I'm lacking the correct terminology for this kind of list so googling is difficult any help is appreciated.

Update
Just to clarify, I will be listening to a websocket

1. Data comes in
2. Convert to object
3. Add to list/array/stack/??

I envisage the class looking like

```
    List<foo> Stack

    AddToStack(Foo)
    {
       Stack.Add(Foo)
    }

    Get20SMA()
    {
        //Gets Last20 objects, does calculation on one property of each object and returns result
    }

    Get100SMA();
    {
        //Gets Last100 objects, does calculation on one property of each object and returns result
    }
```

Comment: do you plan to read off the top or the bottom?

Comment: What do you mean by 'move all elements by one index'? It sounds like you want a ring buffer/deque based on the other requirements.

Comment: If you don't need to access items in your object by `index` then you can use `Stack<T>` and before calling `Push()` check the `Count` property, if it's reached your determined limit, call `Pop` first.

Comment: There's also the `ConcurrentStack<T>` for thread safety, if the above meets your requirements. [concurrentstack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentstack-1?view=net-5.0), [stack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.stack-1?view=net-5.0)

Comment: The behavior described sounds like Queue not Stack.